# KendoUI Upload control - Can't access XMLHttpRequest in upload:

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use the KendoUI file upload widget in ASP.NET WebAPI. The upload is working fine but while I try to access the XMLHttpRequest in upload: it returns as undefined

The docs say to use e.XMLHttpRequest to send any custom header in the upload: but this property is always undefined.

Please help me.

**Ref:** http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload#events-upload

**Code:**

```
<input name="files" id="files" type="file" />

<script src="~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#files").kendoUpload({
        async: {
            async: false,
            saveUrl: '@saveAPIUrl',
            autoUpload: true
        },
        select: function (e) {
            $.each(e.files, function (index, value) {
                if (value.extension != ".csv") {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("Please upload csv files");
                }
            });
        },
        upload: function (e) {
            var _token = getToken();
            var xhr = e.XMLHttpRequest;   // This is return as 'undefined' for xhr
            if (xhr) {
                xhr.addEventListner("readystatechange", function (e) {
                if (xhr.readyState == 1) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("VerificationToken", _token);
                }
            });
        }
        e.data = { userId: userId};
    },
    success: function (e) {
        var response = e.response.split(';');
        clientSetupViewModel.set("file", response[0]);
        clientSetupViewModel.set("clientsetupid", response[1]);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code? It may not be easy to answer you question based on the info you have provided.

Comment: @KhalidHussain i have added the code.